Why such a title does not meet the "quality standards"?
I tried posting a question about understanding a word from a passage in 《左传》 on the site today, but encountered the following problem with the title not meeting the "quality standards." The title was "‘五侯九伯，女实征之’（《齐桓公伐楚盟屈完》）之‘实’字何以训？" Screenshot:

I wonder why this is the case. To my best knowledge, my title "clearly summarizes the problem and uses proper grammar." I wonder what other quality standards are there that my title did not meet.

Fang Jing, I assume it's a bug, as you properly tagged (if there is an algorithm to check Chinese grammar, it probably needs to be revised).
I copied the exact same caracters and that error didn't show up, I wonder if it's a hidden character or simply the encoding that caused it.
Try any of the following:

copy only 五侯九伯，女实征之’（《齐桓公伐楚盟屈完》）之‘实’字何以训？
add Zuo Chuan at the beginning or at the end, in case the subject is requiring some latin characters.
try to reduce the title until the error does not show up anymore, post the question and then try to edit it with the original title.

好运！
